# Differences between AVX and AVX2

Tags: x86, matrix-multiplication, simd, avx, avx2

below is an implementation of a matrix multiply in AVX2. The machine I am using only supports AVX so I am trying to implement the same configuration with AVX.

However, I am having trouble deciphering really what the differences are, and what would needed to be changed! What in this implementation is specific to AVX2 that would not work with a machine only able to process AVX?

This is a link to all the commands for AVX as well as AVX2
https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX

Thank you for any insight at all!

```
 for (uint64_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
     {
         for (uint64_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
         {
             __m256 X = _mm256_setzero_ps();
             for (uint64_t k = 0; k < L; k+= 8) {
                 const __m256 AV = _mm256_load_ps(A+i*L+k);
                 const __m256 BV = _mm256_load_ps(B+j*L+k);
                 X = _mm256_fmadd_ps(AV,BV,X);
             }
             C[i*N+j] = hsum_avx(X);
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code uses AVX1 + FMA instructions, not AVX2.  It would run ok on an AMD Piledriver, for example.  (Assuming the hsum is implemented in a sane way, extracting the high half and then using 128-bit shuffles.).

If your AVX-only CPU doesn't have FMA either, you'd need to use `_mm256_mul_ps` and `_mm256_add_ps`.

---

For Intel, AVX2 and FMA were introduced in the same generation, Haswell, but those *are* different extensions.  FMA is available in some CPUs without AVX2.

There is unfortunately [even a VIA CPU with AVX2 but not FMA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562272/clang-optimizing-using-svml-and-its-autovectorization#comment92123879_52562272), otherwise AVX2 implies FMA unless you're in a VM or [emulator that intentionally has a combination of extensions that real HW doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762372/disabling-avx2-in-cpu-for-testing-purposes).

(There was an FMA4 extension in some AMD CPUs, with 4 operands (3 inputs and a separate output), Bulldozer through Zen1, after Intel pulled a switcheroo on AMD too late for them to change their Bulldozer design to support FMA3.  That's why there's an AMD-only FMA4, and why it wasn't until Piledriver that AMD supported an FMA extension compatible with Intel.  But that's part of the dust pile of history now, so usually we just say FMA to reference the extension that's technically called FMA3.  See Agner Fog's 2009 blog 
[Stop the instruction set war](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=25), and [How do I know if I can compile with FMA instruction sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348909/how-do-i-know-if-i-can-compile-with-fma-instruction-sets))

---

- AVX1: 256-bit FP only (no integer instructions except [`vptest`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ptest), although FP in this case does include bitwise instructions like [`vxorps ymm`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xorps)). Shuffles are only in-lane (e.g. `vshufps ymm` or the new [`vpermilps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermilps)) or with 128-bit granularity (`vperm2f128` or `vinsertf128` / [`vextractf128`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vextractf128:vextractf32x4:vextractf64x2:vextractf32x8:vextractf64x4)).  AVX1 also provides VEX encodings of all SSE1..4 instructions including integer, with 3-operand non-destructive.  e.g. `vpsubb xmm0, xmm1, [rdi]`
- AVX2: 256-bit versions of integer SSE instructions, and new lane-crossing shuffles like `vpermps` / `vpermd` and `vpermq / pd`, and [`vbroadcastss/sd ymm, xmm`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vbroadcast) with a register source (AVX1 only had `vbroadcastss ymm, [mem]`).  Also an efficient `vpblendd` immediate integer blend instruction, like `vblendps`
- FMA3: [`vfmadd213ps x/ymm, x/ymm, x/ymm/mem`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vfmadd132ps:vfmadd213ps:vfmadd231ps) and so on.  (And pd and scalar ss/sd version).  Also fmsub.. (subtract the 3rd operand), fnmadd.. (negate the product), and even fmaddsub...ps.  `_mm256_fmadd_ps` will compile to some form of `vfmadd...ps`, depending on which input operand the compiler wants to overwrite, and which operand it wants to use as the memory operand.

This order of introduction explains the bad choice of intrinsic naming, e.g. `_mm256_permute_ps` (immediate) and `_mm256_permutevar_ps` (vector control) are AVX1 `vpermilps` in-lane permute, with AVX2 getting saddled with `_mm256_permutexvar_ps`.  So confusingly the intrinsic has an `x` for lane-crossing, while the asm mnemonic is just plain.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! For clarification, you are saying I need to use add_ps and mult_ps in combination to replace the FMA instruction fmadd correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what Peter is saying.

Comment: @guts716: Yes, of course.  FMA is just an optimization (of precision and performance) of those operations for a row x column dot product in a matmul.  If FMA isn't available, you have to do it the old fashioned way.